# Why has no one even commented, asked me to clarify or attempted to answer this?

Tags: support, specific-question, unanswered-questions

I asked a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27643460/jquery-combining-combo-box-and-autocomplete a month ago and no one has taken a stab at it. Did I do something wrong? Is it not interesting enough? Is it unanswerable? There is a lot of smart people on here, but why would no one even comment or anything?

Comment: *ouch*, that backfired *so much*:  http://puu.sh/f5V6H/d9c3993774.png.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I took a look and I would say it's because your code is very messy and your question does not seem very clear.  My suggestion would be to pare down your code to a very simple example of what is going wrong and leave out all the other stuff.  Make it 20 lines or less.  BTW, another feeling I have is that you can solve your own question by judicious use of the console.log() function in javascript.

Comment: Thanks Rich, I'll do that and keep that in mind when I post again.

Comment: Good luck and I hope you find a useful answer!  :-)

Comment: I'd add that the tags in the OP's question are wrong. There's a tendency for `jquery-ui` questions which are only tagged as `jquery` to get less attention

Answer (score 8):

I agree with Rich, but I would also say that it probably didn't help being posted at 1am (UTC) on Christmas Day! The traffic on the homepage would likely be the lowest it had been in the whole year!

Comment: The reason this is relevant is that many (most?) questions are answered within the first 10 minutes and then the view count stays more or less the same.